# What is the difference between `joinField` and `joinTable` in collections?

Tags: magento-1, collection, eav

In the file `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php`, there is a function named `joinField` and there is another `joinTable`.

If fields are actually columns in the flat tables, what does it mean to join them? An in what circumstance I should use `joinTable` instead? Can they both be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 6):

Both methods are almost identical, the difference is that `joinField()` only selects a single column from the joined table, while you can specify an array of columns in  joinTable`.

So you can always use `joinTable` instead of `joinField`. The example

```
 joinField('country_name', 'directory/country_name', 'name', 'country_id=shipping_country', "{{table}}.language_code='en'", 'left')
```

is the same as

```
 joinTable('directory/country_name', 'country_id=shipping_country', ['country_name' => 'name'], "{{table}}.language_code='en'", 'left')
```

But `joinField()` should not be used if you need more than one column of the joined table.